# I need to make an exponental equation with subtracting

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation

I have this equation
$$X(1+0.2)^Y$$
Which is simply adding 20% every $Y$ month for the $X$.
For example $$100(1+0.2)^1 = 120$$  $$100(1+0.2)^2  = 144 $$
What I want to do is cutting or rebating 10 every month so it becomes the first month $110$ instead of $120$ and the second one the equation goes like this $110(1+0.2)^2 = 132$ instead of $144$

I tried to do this $$100(1+0.2)^1-10 $$
But it's just cutting $10$ from the total, Which is not exactly what  I want it to do.

Please help me to make the correct equation.

Comment: What about $100(1+0.1)^Y$?

Comment: It will be adding only 10% instead of 20% which will work but only for the 100. because yes the 10% of 100 is 10 but the 10% of 110 is 11

Comment: This question has nothing to do with mathematical physics or the matrix exponential. Tag removed.

Comment: It seems you are looking for

$$100\cdot \left(1+0.20\right)^Y-10\cdot \left(1+0.20\right)^{Y-1}$$

Comment: @user I tried this and it's not giving me the correct answer 
 100(1+0.20)^1-10(1+0.20)^1-1

Comment: @manhat for $Y=1$ we obtain $120-10=110$ and for $Y=2$ we have $144-12=132$

Comment: Thank you for helping dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is unclear, but if I understood correctly, you want to grow 20% and then cut 10 each month, so that if $A_t$ is amount at the end of month $t\geq 1$, we have

$$A_t=RA_{t-1}-r,$$

your problem being the case where
$$A_0=100\\
R=1.2\\
r=10.$$

Induction shows the general solution to this recurrence relation is
$$A_t =A_0 R^t-r\frac{R^t-1}{R-1},R\neq 1\\
A_t =A_0-rt,R= 1.$$

---

UPDATE: As requested in the comments, if the problem is to grow 20% each month and then also cut 10 **percent** each month, the problem is simpler. The amount at the end of month $t\geq 1$ is then given by exactly the same formulas as above, except where

$$A_0=100,R=(1+0.2)(1-0.1)=1.08,r=0.$$

Comment: Hello, Yes thank you this is exactly what I want but can you give me an example because I'm kinda confused with the symbols.

Comment: OMG, It worked with me Thank you, I was trying to solve it for days. Can I private message you so I can thank you and express you how grateful I am <3 I'm soooooo grateful You're the master of math

Comment: @manhat no prob!

Comment: Hey, can I ask for a small edit? I need to make it rebate a percentage instead of (10) like If I have 100 it takes 10% of it every month. Can you do that please?

Comment: @manhat The revised problem sounds simpler! Just to be sure I understood correctly, do you mean the relation is now $A_t=A_{t-1}(1+.2)(1-.1)$ where $A_t$ is the amount at the end of month $t$? If so, the above update is the solution.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Oh my god, you're a life savior. I'm unable to express how grateful I am to you bro.

Comment: Another question. can I make it deduct 10% of the increased value? not the total I mean 100^1(1+0.2)(1-0.1) here it takes 10% of the (120) Can I make it take only 10% of the added 20?

Comment: @manhat How many variations of this problem do you have? lol. Yes, in that case, the relation is $A_t=A_{t-1}(1+0.2(1-.1))$ so it's the same formulas, except with $A_0=100,R=(1+0.2(1-.1))=1.18,r=0$

Comment: Oh yes yes, Lol I'm sorry. I promise this is going to be the last time. I'm making a program to calculate finance things this is it if you wanna look up [Project link](https://github.com/Crybik/EXPAPP/)  Do you allow me to put your name and profile in the credits?, And I'm actually sorry our education system doesn't teach us these things and I'm only 16. if you can suggest a resource to learn math. it'll be superb. Again. my apology and thank you <3

Comment: @manhat No prob--neat project! But I'll pass on being in the credits (honestly, you could probably find the formulas I gave you with some googling). As for learning math, it's hard to suggest something without knowing your background, but some general resources to learn things (math or other subjects) are edX/coursera/MIT OCW.

Comment: Thank you appreciate it :3